# C++ - Does a larger header file with ~1000 defined string constants significantly slow down the compiler?

Tags: c++, compilation, include, header-files

We're developing a game and using the animation Software Spine for many graphical assets. We have around 50 different json files with Spine skeletons and each of them defines many animations, bones, etc. which are all strings.

We built a script that does automatically create a header file with all these constants and ideally we'd like to have them present in all of our UI classes (around 150).

Will simply importing a header file with 1000 `std::string` constants slow down the compile time significantly?

Is there anything we can do to speed it up?

Comment: ... precompiled header.

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem ***now***? How long does it currently take to compile? What is your target compile time? I'd also point out that what you've described as "one large header" is actually quite small. Even so, a large header is much less of an issue than a spider-web of header dependencies between thousands of files. So don't fret over this.

Comment: 1000 std::string constants will slow down execution time. First of all, they will require dynamic initialization, which is pointless for constants. Then how exactly do you declare them? If you declare them as `static` then every translation unit including this header will have its own copy of all the variables.

Comment: Make them `const_expr` to avoid run-time effort; and if you have computer built after 2000, it should take any significant time to compile some thousand constant strings.

Comment: @CraigYoung Thanks for your answers. I have used precompiled headers for iOS, but this game app is made for iOS and Android, so I'm not entirely sure how I can get platform-independant precompiled headers.

Comment: Aganju @VTT Yes, we indeed did this, thank you. Making them const_expr indeed sounds like a very good idea. Thank you. I will look into it! :)
So it will not slow down compilation time to have many constants imported in all kinds of cpp/header files?